# How to give a non sudoer access to a kernel module special device file?

Tags: kernel, permissions

Is it possible to access a kernel module if a user is not sudoer?

I am trying to access a KVM, which is kernel module, as non-sudoer but I am getting an error:

```
Could not access KVM kernel module: Permission denied.
```

Is there any way to make this module accessible to all users (non-sudoers as well) ?

Comment: What are you using to access the kernel module? You could make it so when you run that command with sudo, it does not ask for the password for that command - see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/155827/178596).

Answer (score 2):

A general recipe to set permissions on kernel modules access is to add a file to `/etc/udev/rules.d`. For example, you can create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-kvm.rules` with the following text:

```
KERNEL=="kvm", GROUP="kvm-users"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade**

For `/dev/kvm` specifically, add the user to the `kvm` group with:

```
sudo usermod -a -G kvm $USER
```

and reboot the computer and the problem is solved.

I was getting that error message when passing the `-enable-kvm` to `qemu-system-x86_64`.

How I found it out: if we do:

```
ls -al /dev/kvm
```

it gives:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root kvm 10, 232 May 12 07:53 /dev/kvm
```

and:

```
id -a
```

gives:

```
uid=1000(ciro) gid=1000(ciro) groups=1000(ciro),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),118(lpadmin),128(sambashare)
```

did not contain the `kvm` group.

Maybe access was previously granted through udev rules, but then they moved to the group mechanism? https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1479558#c3

> yes we dropped the kvm udev rules in the rawhide package, since rawhide systemd now provides them. However it looks like you are using the virt-preview repo on f26, so now there isn't anything setting /dev/kvm permissions to 666 and group=kvm

It does seem possible to add users to the `kvm` group during upgrade: [How to run a script only during first install of a package and during upgrades?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101962/script-to-only-execute-during-first-install-of-a-package/102128#102128) but maybe it was not done because of security concerns?