# how to make scripts which will run on installation of apt package

Tags: bash, scripts, system, administration

I have created a bash script which will store some data into a mysql database. Then I have created `deb` file with that script and made it available for installation by creating local apt repository.

Now, I can install that package in any system(`apt-get install packgename`), but the problem is, I have to manually create the mysql database for that script after each installation on each system.

Is there any way so that I can run a script for creating mysql database(as it is a one time requirement for a system) during the installation itself. I have heard something like `post` and `pre` scripts but not getting any idea on googling. Could you guys give some good tutorials for that ?

Comment: They are called package maintainer scripts: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/101962/158442

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets assume you have your `.deb`-file local (If not you can download it via `apt-get download package`).

Unpack your deb file:

```
ar x package.deb
```

Inside the current folder there are now a few files. `data.tar.gz` is the file with the package content. But we're interessted in the file `control.tar.gz`, where the post- and pre-scripts are. So, unpack the control file in another folder:

```
tar xfs control.tar.gz
```

Now, what you search is the script called `postinst`, that is executed after the installation of the package. If that script don't exist, just create it, with `rwxr-xr-x` permissions (755). Inside that script place your db create command, and let the script end with a `exit 0` for a successful installation or `exit 1` for a failure.

When you did all your belongings, `tar` the files back to the control file. Use that command in the folder to create the `control.tar.gz` file.

```
tar -czf control.tar.gz *
```

Now, recreate the deb-package with those new files, with this command:

```
ar r package.deb debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz
```

That's it!

Comment: This worked perfect.

Comment: So, could you tell whether we have an option for making this possible before making `deb` file ? Since, as per your answer, we have already have a deb file. What I am asking is, whether is  there a way we can implement this before making this `deb` file.

Comment: @UvaisIbrahim, it should  be placed in the `debian/` folder.